# What's the difference between the single quote 'a and a' in OCaml?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

The single quote `'a` in OCaml represents a general type. What does `a'` represent? It looks like it's not a grammar error, like in the following code:

```
type nat =
  | O
  | S of nat

let rec plus n m =
  match n with
  | O -> m
  | S n' -> S (plus n' m)
```

Comment: n' is used here to say it is basically n but not exactly. It's just there so you don't confuse the n' with the n 2 lines above.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, 'a is used for type - a general type.

Whereas a' is a valid name for an identifier (value, function...).

In your example, you can substitute `n'` by `nn`.